# Array that would be better sorted in order with merge sort rather than quicksort

Tags: sorting

Can someone give me an example of an array that would be better sorted with its contents in order, with merge sort rather than quicksort?

Comment: Yes. An array that is already sorted will be faster to sort with merge sort than quick sort.

Comment: No I meant what kind of array with its contents currently unsorted would it be better to use merge sort instead of quicksort

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort does more moves, but fewer compares than quicksort. If sorting an array of pointers to strings, only the pointers are being moved, while the strings are being compared. In this type of situation, merge sort is faster.

If sorting an array of integers, counting / radix sort would be fastest. As for merge sort versus quicksort for an array of integers, if running on a processor with 16 registers (8 of them used for pointers to runs), then 4-way merge sort is typically a bit faster than quicksort. A 4-way merge sort does 1.5 x compares, 0.5 x moves, so the total number of operations is the same, but the compares are a bit more cache friendly, and 4-way ends up about 15% or so faster than 2-way.